# What is my professor thinking right now?

Tags: professorship

Professor routinely post lecture notes to the blackboard website. The professor had storage folders for the current and last semester.  After taking an exam, My professor routinely post  the solutions to be studied or compared against your own exams.

While studying for the final, I thought "perhaps he has the exam posted for last year's course?" I looked in last year's file and sure enough , the final is posted with all solutions! Now I have an idea of what to expect.

The day of the final exam comes, I look it over and it is the same exact exam...

Before escorting the class to the testing center, the professor begins to explain that the solution to the final will be posted later that night, and we can expect our final grades by there next morning.

As the class leaves to the testing center , I am the only one left who has yet to leave. I confront my professor and ask him "do you know that the answers to this exam are posted online in last semester's folder?" Frantic he says "why didn't you tell me yesterday?" And he runs off to his office to remove the files.

That was a week ago, my professor never posted the solutions , nor did he post our final grades.

I have a very good relationship with him

What does this mean? Does this make me look bad?

Comment: If I had to guess: He's probably thinking "Oh no, I really f***ed up this time, now I have to figure out how to grade this class under these circumstances" and is not thinking about _you_ at all. But obviously nobody here can know what your professor is thinking, so I'm going to have to close this question.

Comment: I'm literally ROFL :D

Comment: _Does this make me look bad?_ It's not your fault. Frankly, I would not have said anything before the exam if I were you. How would you know the exam problems and solutions in that folder would be the same this year?

Comment: Unwittingly posting solutions is hardly ideal, and I can understand why the professor would be upset with himself. That said, students still had to learn the material well enough to rewrite it on the exam, so all is not lost. He may have felt like a chump as he marched off, but the situation might not have been as dire as the professor initially thought.

Comment: In practice, only the good and conscientious students will have checked last year's exam. They will get a better grade than the already good grade they would have gotten otherwise. The bad students would not have had the motivation to check last year's exam, or to look through it in sufficient detail to remember it during the exam. They will get the bad grade that they would otherwise also would have gotten. So while the situation is not ideal, the number of students who this will likely affect is, in my practical experience teaching for 10 years, not going to be very large.

Comment: He never posted our grades, it's like he's thinking "what's the point" . I'll wait and see